# RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering

Tags: webgl2

So i'm trying to use WebGL to offload some of the data processing needed for the image later.

I have two stages, first I'm trying 'render' unsigned ints to a texture.
On the second pass, I read from this texture and render to the canvas.

If i define the texture as RGBA than I have no problems. But when I change the format to RGBA32UI, I keep getting:

```
RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering
```

I reduced my shaders to a single pixel and still getting the same error.

Texture is initialized like this :

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

{
  var level = 0;
  var internalFormat = gl.RGBA32UI;
  var border = 0;
  var format = gl.RGBA_INTEGER;
  var type = gl.UNSIGNED_INT;
  var data = null;
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
    1, 1, border, format, type, data);

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

var level = 0;
var attachmentPoint = gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1;
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, attachmentPoint, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, level);
```

and inside the fragment shader I have two color types :

```
layout(location = FLOAT_COLOR_LOCATION) out vec4 float_color;
layout(location = UINT_COLOR_LOCATION) out uvec4 uint_color;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're using COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 and skipping COLOR_ATTACHMENT0.

IIRC you need to start at attachment 0 and work your way up.

Also you should probably be checking the framebuffer is complete with `gl.checkFramebufferStatus`

Also, integer textures are not filterable so you need to change `gl.LINEAR` to `gl.NEAREST`

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");

testAttachment(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
testAttachment(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

function testAttachment(attachmentPoint) {

  function createTexture() {
    var texture = gl.createTexture();

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    var level = 0;
    var internalFormat = gl.RGBA32UI;
    var border = 0;
    var format = gl.RGBA_INTEGER;
    var type = gl.UNSIGNED_INT;
    var data = null;
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
      1, 1, border, format, type, data);

    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    return texture;
  }
  
  var texture = createTexture();

  var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

  var level = 0;
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, attachmentPoint, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, level);

  const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);

  console.log(glEnumToString(gl, attachmentPoint), glEnumToString(gl, status));
  
  if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    return;
  }
  
  const vs = `#version 300 es
  void main() {
     gl_Position = vec4(0,0,0,1);
     gl_PointSize = 100.0;
  }
  `;
  const fs = `#version 300 es
  uniform highp usampler2D color;
  out uvec4 outColor;
  void main() {
    outColor = texture(color, gl_PointCoord);
  }
  `;
  
  const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  gl.useProgram(prg);
  
  // need a different input texture than output texture
  const inTex = createTexture();
  
  // no need to set uniforms since they default to 0
  // so using texture unit 0
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

  // check that it rendered without error
  console.log(glEnumToString(gl, gl.getError()));
}

function glEnumToString(gl, value) {
  if (value === 0) { 
    return "NONE";
  }
  for (let key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === value) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return "0x" + value.toString(16);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It didn't help.
I still get the same error from the second draw call.

Comment: Then you have 2 problems. Without putting on attachment 0 my sample returns `FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`. On attachment 0 it returns `FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`. Actually I'm pretty sure your second problem is that you can't use `LINEAR` filtering on integer textures

Comment: I added the use of your useful function 'glEnumToString'. 
It returned FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE in both times.

Comment: Updated the sample to test both, it returns FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED for me with attachment 1. [See screenshot](https://imgur.com/o6EBwL5)

Comment: :-O 
Didn't notice it was LINEAR! it was suppose to be NEAREST.
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Another follow up question.

How do I make the first draw call use attachment 0. 
and the second draw call to use attachment 1? 
As you can see above, I have different types of outputs.

Comment: Your question says first you render to a texture, then you render to the canvas. So you only need one attachment. Then bind `null` as the framebuffer to render to the canvas. If you want to render to 2 things at different times make 2 framebuffers each with one attachment. Having 2 attachments is for rendering to 2 things at the same time.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I can't use the same color attachment for different output types. 
Texture output is uvec4. While the output for the canvas is vec4.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your question. Maybe you should ask a new one for these other issues.